# Not receiving all the data while subscribe to mqtt broker from python client

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, messagebroker, mosca

I have a mosca mqtt broker up and running. I connect to the broker from a python client, subscribe to a particular topic to receive data. I am facing a issue of data loss while receiving the data. My code

```
broker_address=""
port = ""

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    time = datetime.now()
    print("message received at: "+str(time))


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("connected OK Returned code=",rc)
        time = datetime.now()
        print(time)
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)

    print("Subscribing to topic","data/#")
    client.subscribe("data/#")


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
   print("Client Got Disconnected")
   print('rc value '+str(rc))
   time = datetime.now()
   print(time)
   if rc != 0:
       print('Unexpected MQTT disconnection. Will auto-reconnect')

   else:
       print('rc value:' + str(rc))


def mqttConnection():
    client = mqtt.Client(clean_session=True) #create new instance
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message #attach function to callback
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
    print("connecting to broker")
    client.connect(broker_address, port=port) #connect to broker
    client.loop_forever() #stop the loop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mqttConnection()
```

and the console output

```
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:31:59.779071
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:31:59.788275
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:31:59.804362
Client Got Disconnected
rc value 1
2019-11-15 13:32:00.819480
Unexpected MQTT disconnection. Will auto-reconnect
connected OK Returned code= 0
2019-11-15 13:32:01.863997
Subscribing to topic data/#
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:02.678528
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:02.970585
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:03.858506
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:04.062929
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:04.210075
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:04.494648
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:04.838279
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:04.840228
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:06.209856
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:07.731949
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:07.985341
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:08.084985
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:08.783509
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:32:09.255180
Client Got Disconnected
rc value 1
2019-11-15 13:33:02.293644
Unexpected MQTT disconnection. Will auto-reconnect
connected OK Returned code= 0
2019-11-15 13:33:03.326783
Subscribing to topic data/#
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:33:04.214865
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:33:04.668272
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:33:04.774607
message received at: 2019-11-15 13:33:07.299220
```

First time when it has disconnected, it re connected and started receiving messages immediately within a second.But for the second disconnection, there is a time difference of a minute between the last message and the time printed from the disconnect call back. The data in this one minute difference is lost. But if I check for data using MQTT Lens, where i am connect to the broker address and subscribe to the same topic, i could see data for that one minute also.  So there is data being sent by broker but the python client is not able to receive it. Why is it not able to receive that data in that one minute if its disconnecting after a minute. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is how MQTT works. By default a subscriber can only receive messages that arrive while it is subscribed. With the retain flag set it can also receive the last message (singular) send before it subscribed. If you need guaranteed delivery,  there's a QoS feature in MQTT.

Comment: Hi, I am referring to the data lost before disconnection. between `2019-11-15 13:32:09.255180` and the time of diconnection `2019-11-15 13:33:02.293644`. the data in this time frame should have been received , right ?

Comment: By whom? By the subscribing client while it was not subscribed?

Comment: by the subscribing client. if you see the logs, its subcribed at `2019-11-15 13:32:01.863997`,  till `2019-11-15 13:32:09.255180` its recieving data. At `2019-11-15 13:33:02.293644` it disconnected. so for the time interval between `2019-11-15 13:32:09.255180` and `2019-11-15 13:33:02.293644`, client is still subscribed, right?

Comment: It was disconnected around that time: `Client Got Disconnected` at around 13:32:09.2. Without a known reason for the disconnect it is not safe to assume any message was received.

Comment: if you see the on_disconnect call back, client got disconnected at `2019-11-15 13:33:02.293644` right?

Comment: That is the moment it was noticed that it is disconnected. The actual disconnect  might have happened earlier. TCP sockets don't have a trivial timeline.

Comment: The timestamp is all on the client side, so you have no way of knowing if you are missing messages. If the subscriptions is at greater than QOS 0 then the broker may be queuing the missed messages and delivering them on reconnect, but you have no way to see that with the code you have.

Comment: okay, got your points.thanks, one way i was ascertaining I was missing messages by checking in the MQTT Lens. I was receiving data on MQTT Lens for the time interval between `2019-11-15 13:32:09.255180` and `2019-11-15 13:33:02.293644`

Comment: That is meaningless, just because another client is receiving messages in this case shows nothing useful. Also as has been the case over all your questions, you haven't been looking at WHY the client is disconnecting or supplied ANY data from the broker that would help.

Comment: Hi @hardillb, I don't have access to the server where broker is running. anyways thats the first thing i will try now. getting the logs of broker.